# AlertDialog with EditText in method: The local variable editText may not have been initialized

Tags: java, android

In my app I am using AlertDialog with EditText. I want to move this code to method because it called few times. I try to implement it by this way:

```
private EditText showEditAlert(DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle(R.string.waypoint);
    alert.setMessage(R.string.waypoint_alert_text);
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(editText);
    alert.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, listener);
    alert.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null);
    alert.show();
    return editText;
}
```

And then I want to use it:

```
final EditText editText = showEditAlert(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Here is I am working with editText
        // and here is I get error "The local variable editText may not have been initialized"
    }
});
```

But I get "The local variable editText may not have been initialized" error. As I understand compiler think that the onClick() method will called before showEditAlert() returns value.

How to implement this correctly? Or may be I can just suppress this error?

Comment: Is it an error or warning given by the editor ?

Comment: @amd, that is error given by the editor (Eclipse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the IDE's warning is precisely for the reason you suppose. I guess you could circumvent this by defining a custom interface for the listener (and it would probably be more clear to use, to boot). Something like:

```
interface EditAlertOkListener
{
    void onEditAlertOk(EditText editText);
}

private void showEditAlert(final EditAlertOkListener listener)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    ...
    final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(editText);
    alert.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
            if (listener != null)
                listener.onEditAlertOk(editText);
        }
    }); 

    alert.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null);
    alert.show();
}
```

And then just call it with:

```
    showEditAlert(new EditAlertOkListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEditAlertOk(EditText editText) {
            // Use editText here.
        }
    });
```

PS. You can also have the method return the `EditText`, if needed, I just removed it to make this example clearer. Or also, if you just need the `EditText` contents, have the interface pass a `CharSequence` or `String` instead of the `EditText` itself. This is just a template. :)

Comment: Thank you for answer! I see you are suggesting make custom listener for it. I think about this too, but I hope to do it with built-in listeners only. But it looks like that is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Because the editText variable may not be initialized. The IDE could not check it when it is creating.

The solution here is use the keyword: "this"

```
final EditText editText = showEditAlert(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        this.getText();// this mean editText, not its parent, if you want to use parent, you must have ParentClass.this
    }
});
```